# Non Api routing with SPA and Web Api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I have been trying for a few days to solve this problem so I may in fact be trying to solve the wrong problem or don't know the right terms to search so here goes.

I'm creating a SPA with AngularJS and Web Api (4.5). All of my views are client side. So the server doesn't know all the possible routes that may become present in the URI. This isn't a problem until a user uses one of the browser controls (back, forward, refresh, history) and the server attempts to route the requested URI.

My thoughts on dealing with this have centered around mapping all non API routes to the root of the application.

So I would like to either, know the correct syntax for MapHttpRoute to pick up any route that does not attempt to reference controllers (API's) or if there is a better method for dealing with this problem.

```
public static void Register( HttpConfiguration config )
{
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();            

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
    //
    //  This doesn't work 
    //
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "Default",
        routeTemplate: "{*catchall}"
    );
}
```

```
    This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
    
    
    No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:9234/login'.
    
    
    No route providing a controller name was found to match request URI 'http://localhost:9234/login'
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a good idea, just workaround

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "Default",
            routeTemplate: "{*catchall}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Spa"}
            );

[AllowAnonymous]
public sealed class SpaController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        var indexHtml = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/index.html");

        var stringContent = new StreamContent(File.OpenRead(indexHtml));
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) {Content = stringContent};

        return response;
    }
}
```